# discord.py join position return <Member id=myid name='nameofbot' discriminator='mydiscordtag'

Tags: discord, discord.py

```
sorted_members = sorted(ctx.guild.members, key=lambda m:m.joined_at)
        ind = sorted_members.index(ctx.author) + 1
```

variable `ind` should show your guild join position but it print the text:

> ```
> <Member id=myid name='nameofbot' discriminator='mydiscordtag' bot=True
> nick=None guild=<Guild id=guildid name="nameofguild" shard_id=None
> chunked=False member_count=3>>
> ```

and variable `sorted_members` prints the same thing but not like error it print it. I don't know what the problem is, maybe with the type of variable?

**EDITED:** I tried code from comments

```
sorted_members = sorted(ctx.guild.members, key=lambda m:m.joined_at)
sorted_ids = [m.id for m in sorted_members]
ind = sorted_ids.index(ctx.author.id) + 1
```

and have this error:

> ```
> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ?>ValueError: myid is not in list
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list that contain all of the members' id and check your id in that list. This is a better way for avoid from errors.

```
sorted_members = sorted(ctx.guild.members, key=lambda m:m.joined_at)
sorted_ids = [m.id for m in sorted_members]
ind = sorted_ids.index(ctx.author.id) + 1
```

Comment: error: `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ValueError: myid is not in list`